# I saw the sun red

Tags: grammar

a)  I saw the sun be red.                    wrong

b)  I saw the sun to be red.                 wrong

c)  I saw the sun red.                       correct

d)  Then sun is seen to be red.              correct

e)  The sun is seen red.                     correct

Am I right in my conclusions on the use of grammar here? Thank You!

Comment: All are grammatical. None are idiomatic, though I can think of circumstances where some of them might be used: most likely d)

Comment: This isn't a very natural sentence, because the sun isn't really red, it only appears red under certain conditions, so we would say 'it looks red' rather than 'it is seen to be red'. Grammatically, most of your conclusions are correct. (e) is not correct, and (b) could be correct when speaking of a different subject.  _I trained my binoculars on the distant figure and saw it to be a man in dark clothing._

Comment: I suppose it all depends  on context, but the most likely scenario would be *I saw the setting sun and it appeared [to be] red*. Then ther are the more dramatic scenarios, due to various atmospheric conditions, such as *the noonday sun was red*

Comment: I think this question probably needs more clarity.  Colin Fine had it right in the first comment: all of them are (at least potentially) grammatical, but none of them sound very natural.  You might use some of them in a poetic sense.

Comment: Colin Fine,  
Kate Bunting,  
Peter Jennings, stangdon thank you all very much! For me this grammar aspect is very confusing, so thank you for help!